# How to show that two representations are equivalent?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am reading the [lecture notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/courses/mat1197/notes.pdf). On page 14, example of $C_{c}^{\infty}(G)$. I am trying to show that the map $A$ takes $f$ to $g\mapsto f(g^{-1})$ is an invertible element of $\operatorname{Hom}_G(\lambda, \rho)$.

By the definition of invertible elements, we only need to show that $A$ satisfies the following identity
$$
(\rho(g)A)(f)(x)=(A\lambda(g))(f)(x), x\in G.
$$
We have $$ (\rho(g)A)(f)(x) = \rho(g)(A(f)(x))=f(g^{-1}x^{-1}), \quad (1) $$
$$ (A\lambda(g))(f)(x) = (Af(g^{-1}x))=f(x^{-1}g). \quad (2) $$
But (1) and (2) are different. I am confusing. Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equation is not correct:
In fact, $$A(\lambda(g)f)(x)=A(f(g^{-1}x))=f(g^{-1}x^{-1}).$$
Why? Since $A$ takes $f$ to the function that sends $x$ to $f(x^{-1}),$ we find that $A(\lambda(g)f)$ sends $x$ to $\lambda(g)f(x^{-1})=f(g^{-1}x^{-1}).$
Hope this helps.

Comment: In more brief terms, the action of $A$ takes the variable $x$ to $x^{-1},$ and our variable is $x$, not $g^{-1}x.$